# Fullscreen vlc with controls at the bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to css and going to make a VLC embed into a fullscreen webpage (a kiosk app) with some controls at bottom of the screen.

can you tell me how css should be written?

```
---------------------------------------------------------
|div-doc                                                |           
|+-----------------------------------------------------+|
|| div-vlc                                             ||
||                                                     ||
||                                                     ||
||                                                     ||
||                  MOIVE HERE                         ||
||                                                     || no y-scroll
||                                                     ||
||                                                     ||
||                                                     ||
||                                                     ||
|+-----------------------------------------------------+|
|+-----------------------------------------------------+|
||div-control                                          ||
|+-----------------------------------------------------+|
---------------------------------------------------------
                    no x-scroll
note: 1. div-doc has 2 sub-divs (div-vlc and div-control)
      2. div-control always at bottom
      3. background of everything should be black
```

Thanks Guys

--EDIT 1--

```
body{background:black}
#div-doc { width: 100%; height: 100% }
#div-vlc { height: 95%}
#div-control {height: 5%}
```

But why i'm still getting y-scroll when div-doc specifies 100%?

Comment: How far have you got your CSS to? Can you show us?

Answer (score 1):

A simple CSS to show the layout over the full page with out the scroll bar would be something like this

```
body { margin:0; padding:0; overflow: hidden; }
#div-doc { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

Comment: You cannot ask the community to write the CSS for you @c2h2, show us your work first? I am supposing you can do the rest.

Comment: hi @Starx can you give me a little bit hint on how can div-vlc and div-control has the height to fit a full screen? (div-control has a fixed height)

Comment: I think you have a mix a little bit the JS, a simple CSS is something like http://jsfiddle.net/43Grq/5/ but as you can see, a height has to be initiated for this CSS to fit perfectly, and that's where JS comes in.

Answer (score 1):

If the Window is not going to be resized, then you can use position:fixed; on the divs and position them relative to the window. So you can position the bottom most div below, and the VLC item on top of that.

This would work well because the controls are -presumably- fixed in size (i.e image buttons).